# Dividing tasks among Goroutines concurrently

Tags: go, concurrency

#### What this code does

The code gets data from a Postgresql database. From all the data only two fields (Session and Text) are added to `Task Struct`.

There are only 2 (each) of the mentioned data in my DB, meaning on doing a `len(task)` will return me `2` as the output.

**Now from here on is what the problem is :**

I make a `buffered channel ch` with a length equal to that of the task struct (here in this case,2).

I specify the Max number of workers (threads) allowed, here that is 20.

What the code below does is when I send the task into the channel sends all the elements in the `Task struct` (here, 2) and the example code in Task struct will print all of it twice (= length of Task struct). Example is shown at the end.

#### What I need for this program to do

For example there are 100 data in the channel `len(task) = 100`. I want to divide these 100 data into 20 Goroutines which will take care of 5 data each (I don't know if this is possible, please provide some other solution if this is invalid).

So the 100 data will be provided to 20 workers and they would take in 5 data each and run tasks with them and on end the channel would close and thats it.

This will be helpful when the database gets larger and currently too.

Which would be better 20 Workers do tasks each or making number of Workers equal to number of Data in the channel?

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

type Task struct {
    FetchedSession string
    FetchedText    string
}

func FetchAllData() {

    var task []Task

    //Fetch Session from DB
    var sess []database.UserSession
    database.DB.Find(&sess)
    //Fetch CommentText from DB
    var cmt []database.CommentReq
    database.DB.Find(&cmt)

    if len(sess) == len(cmt) {
        for i := range sess {
            task = append(task, Task{FetchedSession: sess[i].Session, FetchedText: cmt[i].CommentText})
        }
    }

    //making the Task Channel
    ch := make(chan []Task, len(task))

    MAX_WORKERS := 20

    wg.Add(MAX_WORKERS)

    for i := 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                t, ok := <-ch
                if !ok {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
                DoTasks(t)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(task); i++ {
        ch <- task
    }

    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}

//Since Total number of data in Database is 2 (rows)
//Currently this function takes all data from the channel and runs Twice
func DoTasks(t []Task) {

    //Total tasks (data) = 100
    //If Max Workers = 20, then this function will run 5 times
    //Each Goroutine will get 4 tasks from the channel
    // Get the FetchedSession and FetchedTask and do tasks

    fmt.Println(t) // This prints all data twice

    //Finish one task and continue with the second
}
```

Example:

```
Example Data:
Task{FetchedSession: "EncodedString",  FetchedText: "Hello"}
Task{FetchedSession: "ExampleString",  FetchedText: "Hi"}
//Output
EncodedString
Hello
ExampleString
Hi
EncodedString
Hello
ExampleString
Hi
```

Comment: The optimal number of workers depends on the task and the available resources.  Also, there is no reason why an efficient implementation would necessarily have each worker complete the same number of tasks

Comment: @HymnsForDisco, thanks! So how should I go about doing this program?

Comment: Your code iterates over `task`, and for each element, sends the entire `task` slice over the channel to be worked on. Presumably it should only send each element once. You should also probably be using `range` on the channel in your goroutine.

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for your help. Can you please make the changes necessary to my program and post in an answer below. I am very new to Golang and therefore have quite problem with Goroutines and channels.

Comment: "So the 100 data will be provided to 20 workers and they would take in 4 data" - this math seems off.

Comment: You need to do enough math for your question to make sense. 20 workers, 4 tasks each is 80 tasks. Where should the other 20 tasks go?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the question was already resolved without regard for this issue.  Sometimes these details are not integral to the question, but it is just the asker trying to show their effort and putting forward a (potentially confused) idea about the solution.  The question says that they are not sure if 20 is the right number of workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change the task channel type.

```
ch := make(chan Task, len(task))
```

This means that each value passed on the channel represents a *single* task.

- Simplify your channel iteration

```
    for i := 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for t := range ch {
                DoTask(t)
            }
        }()
    }
```

`wg.Done()` will now be run when the worker exits. `range ch` will stop after the channel is closed and all tasks are consumed.

- Change "Do" function to match

```
func DoTask(t Task) {
```

About how to choose the number of workers:

[Run some benchmarks](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go) for your `FetchAllData` function, and try changing `MAX_WORKERS` (or passing it as a parameter). The optimal value will depend on the task, and the available resources at the time of running the function, meaning the best value on your machine today might not be the best value on anyone else's machine, or your machine tomorrow. A benchmark should help you find a good approximate range to put the value in.